# What kinds of strategies are there for paging result sets for web UIs?

Tags: pagination

I am looking at implementing a paging strategy for a domain model which has numbers in the hundreds of thousands. I am most interested in how websites that are performance conscience achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I use in a SQL Server 2008 table that has 2 billion + rows of data (I changed the table and column names)

it takes between 6 and 10 milliseconds to do a page of 50 rows, 5000 rows per page takes about 60 milliseconds

```
; with cte as(select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by Column1,Column2) as RowNumber, 
 <<Other columns here>>
        from Table1 p
        join Table2 i on i.ID = p.ID
                and i.ID2 = p.ID2
        join dbo.Table3 c on i.ID2 = p.ID2
        where Column2 between  @StartDate and @EndDate
        and p.ID = @ID
        )


        select *,(select MAX(RowNumber) from cte) as MaxRow
        from cte
        where RowNumber between @StartRow and (@StartRow +  @RowsPerPage) -1
        order by Col3
```

I use page level compression on the DB, narrow tables and indexes also

That is on the database, on the website we use a ExtJS grid and it is just Ajax calls to the service which calls the DB

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.net/default.aspx).

[Here's](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx) a demo with 100,000 rows.